# inkscape) remove part of object which is outside of another object

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have two circles.
One small blue circle and one big pink circle.

Blue circle intersects the pink circle like the image
[image]

I want remove just the part of blue ball which is outside of pink ball. I tried to select both two balls and do difference but it also removes the part of blue ball which is inside of pink ball

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know about [Boolean operations in Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html)?

Comment: @BillyKerr No. I watched some online youtube tutorials and they didnt do anything with boolean.

Comment: That's strange, because these boolean operations are like the basics of vector image editing software such as Inkscape. The answer given by @Pinback explains how to do it using one of the boolean operations (Exclusion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure they are both path objects -

Path -> Object to Path

Duplicate the red circle, select the two circles you want to work on then use the pathing tools

Path -> Exclusion, 
Path -> Break Apart

discard the lower circle remnant.

Comment: 'Path > Object to Path' is not needed (anymore?), Inkscape will convert the circles automatically.

Comment: it depends  - 0.92 is still the latest for some platforms which doesn't do this and will not behave as expected as a result

Comment: 0.92.3 does, and 0.92.2, too, as well as 0.91... (these are the ones I have installed)

Comment: Not on 0.92.2 OSX it doesn't which is what I used - no path effects will work on circle or rectangles unless you convert them. However good to know that at some point in the future the behaviour will be more intuitive.

Comment: This is not a path effect, but a Boolean operation. Can you test again, please? And make a bug report if that is true?

Comment: Pathing tools are not "pathing effects" maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by 'Pathing tools' :-(